# set state with array/object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react.js app I have this array in state:

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    userRecord: {
        userName: '',
        userEmail: '',
        userAge: '',
        userHeight: '',
        userRace: '',
        userGender: '',
        createdAt: undefined,
        updatedAt: undefined
      }
   }
 }
```

then I call a function where I'm trying to set the state of each value

```
    this.setState({
        userRecord.userName: newuserDocs[0].userName,
        userRecord.userAge: newuserDocs[0].userAge,
        userRecord.userHeight: newuserDocs[0].userHeight,
        userRecord.userRace: newuserDocs[0]. userRace,
        userRecord.userGender: newuserDocs[0].userGender,
        userRecord.userEmail: newuserDocs[0].userEmail,
      });
```

But I'm getting an error that the period between userRecord and each value is incorrect.

How do I properly set the state of those values?

Comment: `In my react.js app I have this array in state` no you don't have array in state

Comment: you updating your OBJECT in state - using wrong syntax

Comment: @CodeManiac I meant object,. I have an array too, but I removed it from the example when posting and didn't update my text

Comment: get object: var userRecord = this.state.userRecord;

then update object e.g.:  userRecord.userName: newuserDocs[0].userName;

then commit state: this.setState ({ userRecord });

Comment: @developer yes I meant object, I had an array too but I removed it and didn't update my question text when posting. What is the proper syntax here though?

Comment: @TomN. no problem :) does the linked question solves your problem. try once if you still face error let us know

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks! I'll check it now